# Publishing mocks for an npm package to be used by jest's module mocking system

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am publishing a (private) npm package and would like to publish mocks for it as well. I want these mocks to be picked up by jest's [module mocking system.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html)

The package is a react library that uses context and makes network requests. All of the library's functionality is self contained and fully tested. I would like the consumer to be able to treat this as a black box in tests, trusting that it works as expected. Thus, I would like to publish a mocked version of it for testing sake.

```
// The real component
const ComplicatedComponent = props => {
  // Access context here
  return <div> Something based on context <div/>
}

// The mocked component

const ComplicatedComponent = props => <>ComplicatedComponent</>
```

In a perfect world the consumer would simply be able to call

```
jest.mock('my-library');
```

As far as I can tell [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#mocking-node-modules): this is not possible out of the box. This seems to imply it is up to the consumer to write the mocks:

> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the mock should be placed in the **mocks** directory adjacent to node_modules

Can anyone suggest a good approach to publishing mocks for my library to be used by jest?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this myself - did you have any luck working out a solution?

Comment: I don’t remember offhand, but I think that the best way to do it would be to have the mock as an export, than manually mocking it in the setup.

Comment: Buler? ... Buler? ... Buler? ...

Comment: I did finally figure out how to do this. I included the modules that needed mocking in the regular __ mock __ subdirectory within my npm module. Then, within the code that imports the module, `jest.mock('<npm_module>/path/to/mocked/code')`, will use the mocked version of that npm module code.

Comment: Can you use `moduleNameMapper` in jest.config.js to map the component you want to mock to its mock in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting [this comment from @Sean22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442280/publishing-mocks-for-an-npm-package-to-be-used-by-jests-module-mocking-system#comment118125458_58442280) as the answer:

> I did finally figure out how to do this. I included the modules that needed mocking in the regular __ mock __ subdirectory within my npm module. Then, within the code that imports the module, jest.mock('<npm_module>/path/to/mocked/code'), will use the mocked version of that npm module code

So, make sure your `__mocks__/custom-mock.js` is included in the build for your package, and consuming apps will be able to use it